# Create custom testcontainer modules?

Tags: java, junit5, testcontainers

I am using JUnit5 + Testcontainers.

I see there are Testcontainer modules such as these: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/tree/main/modules

I would like to build my own Testcontainers custom module.

Is there a way for developers to build their own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can extend the `GenericContainer` class. By overriding methods like `containerIsStarted` or adding your own methods, you can customize the container's behavior.

Have a look at how these modules are implemented, e.g., [the MongoDB one](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/main/modules/mongodb/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/MongoDBContainer.java). It overrides `containerIsStarted` to initialize a replica set:

```
@Override
protected void containerIsStarted(InspectContainerResponse containerInfo, boolean reused) {
    if (reused && isReplicationSetAlreadyInitialized()) {
        log.debug("Replica set already initialized.");
    } else {
        initReplicaSet();
    }
}
```